# How can I make the ion-tab-buttons work with vue-router? (with Ionic 6 and Vue.js 3)

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs3, vue-router, ionic6

I'm building a tabs page with Ionic 6 and Vue.js 3 but I cant use the router-link in the button and I dont understand why...
The following example doesnt work

```
    <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
      <ion-tab-button tab="details" :router-link="{ name: 'details' }">
        <ion-label >Details</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>
    </ion-tab-bar>
```

The router link works on regular buttons...

```
    <ion-button :router-link="{ name: 'details' }">Details</ion-button>
```

I have **a patch** for the time being, which is adding the router link to the label instead, but I need to be very precise when I click as if I click on the image it doesnt work...

```
    <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
      <ion-tab-button tab="details">
        <ion-label :router-link="{ name: 'details' }">Details</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>
    </ion-tab-bar>
```

I have a second issue when changing between tabs...
I believe when I click on a tab it should appear immediately, but the new tab fades in...